# Java: Implementing Merge Sort

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I want to implement Merge Sort using one a mergeSort method that splits the sequences of an int array up until it's a single element and using a method merge to put them together.
With my code as it is I get a Stackoverflow Error.
Anyone has an idea why?

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] seq) {
    return mergeSort(seq, 0, seq.length - 1);
}
private static int[] mergeSort(int[] seq, int l, int r) {

    if (seq.length < 2) {
        return seq;
    }
    int s = (l + r) / 2;
    int[] a = new int[s];
    int[] b = new int[seq.length - s];
    for (int i : a) {
        a[i] = seq[i];
    }
    for (int j : b) {
        b[j] = seq[s + j];
    }
    mergeSort(a);
    mergeSort(b);

    return merge(a, b);
}

public static int[] merge(int[] ls, int[] rs) {
    // Store the result in this array
    int[] result = new int[ls.length + rs.length];

    int i, l, r;
    i = l = r = 0;
    while (i < result.length) {
        if (l < ls.length && r < rs.length) {
            if (ls[l] < rs[r]) {
                result[i] = ls[l];
                ++i;
                ++l;
            } else {
                result[i] = rs[r];
                ++i;
                ++r;
            }
        } else if (l >= ls.length) {
            while (r < rs.length) {
                result[i] = rs[r];
                ++i;
                ++r;
            }
        } else if (r >= rs.length) {
            while (l < ls.length) {
                result[i] = ls[l];
                ++i;
                ++l;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow is caused by calling the method recursively too many times, possibly infinitely.

`private static int[] mergeSort(int[] seq, int l, int r)` this will always be called with l=0 and r=seq.length-1, so it's not really necessary to overload.

Here: `int s = (l + r) / 2;` if the array has 2 elements, this will return 0 (l=0, r=1), so the array will be split to a length 0, and a length 2 (and here is what causes the infinite recursive calls). Add one to the result, and the splitting of the array will work correctly.

To copy the parts of the original array, it's easier to use Arrays.copyOfRange() than writing your own for loop. And you're trying to use the existing elements of arrays `a` and `b`, which will all be 0, for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two small issues with your code.

First one is here:

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] seq) {
    return mergeSort(seq, 0, seq.length - 1);
}
```

You need to call it as  `return mergeSort(seq, 0, seq.length);`

The reason behind that is that for example when you have 2 elements and you call it like that with -1 you pass an array with 2 elements but s=1+0/2 =0 and you don't actually split it. Each subsequent recursion call is done with one empty array and one array with the same 2 elements causing an infinite loop and a stackoverflow exception

The second problem is this one:

```
  for (int i : a) {  and   for (int i : b) {
```

You can't do the for loop like because you want to iterate on indexes not values of the array. You need to change it to:

```
   for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = seq[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        b[i] = seq[s + i];
    }
```

And the last problem with your code is that you don't assign the values of the resulting sorted array and when you do the recursive calls it returns the sorted sub part but you don't get the result. It should become:

```
a=mergeSort(a);
b=mergeSort(b);
```

And here is the final code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] array={3,9,4,5,1} ;
        array=mergeSort(array);
        for(int i:array) {
            System.out.print(i+",");    
        }
    }


    private static int[] mergeSort(int[] seq) {

        if (seq.length < 2) {
            return seq;
        }
        int s = seq.length / 2; //You always use that value. no need for 2 methods
        int[] a = new int[s];
        int[] b = new int[seq.length - s];
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            a[i] = seq[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
            b[i] = seq[s + i];
        }
        a=mergeSort(a);
        b=mergeSort(b);

        return merge(a, b);
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] ls, int[] rs) {
        // Store the result in this array
        int[] result = new int[ls.length + rs.length];

        int i, l, r;
        i = l = r = 0;
        while (i < result.length) {
            if (l < ls.length && r < rs.length) {
                if (ls[l] < rs[r]) {
                    result[i] = ls[l];
                    ++i;
                    ++l;
                } else {
                    result[i] = rs[r];
                    ++i;
                    ++r;
                }
            } else if (l >= ls.length) {
                while (r < rs.length) {
                    result[i] = rs[r];
                    ++i;
                    ++r;
                }
            } else if (r >= rs.length) {
                while (l < ls.length) {
                    result[i] = ls[l];
                    ++i;
                    ++l;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! So I changed what you said and now it works, but not perfectly. For a given array {3,9,4,5,1} I get {3,4,5,1,9} as the result, although it should be {1,3,4,5,9}. I can't wrap my head around the line where I am wrong with this..